# How to extract random words from .txt file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
Title       | Author

-------------------------
title1      | author1

title2      | author2


...        ...

titleN      | authorN
```

I want to extract 100 random titles from this file, like this:

```
title1

title2

...

title100
```

I tried this:

```
import random
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
  title = f.read().split('|')

for i in range (0,100):
 print(random.choice(title))
```

But during the execution, the program prints also random authors name. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Do you want the possibility of duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
with open(path,'r') as f:
    title = f.read().split('|')
```

`f.read()` gives you the whole files as a string. Splitting that on `|` gives a list with both authors and titles (and new lines and spaces).

Instead, you can process the lines and split as you go. With something like:

```
with open(path) as f:
    titles = [l.split('|')[0].strip() for l in f]
```

This will give you a clean list of titles like:

```
['title1', 'title2', 'title3', 'title4', 'title5']
```

With that you can use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to get however many random items you want.

```
import random

path = "path/to/file.txt"
n = 100

with open(path) as f:
    titles = [l.split('|')[0].strip() for l in f]

random.sample(titles, n)
```

This assumes you don't want duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.readlines()` instead of `.read()` to read the file line by line to a list. Then you can use `.split('|')[0].strip()` after when you've selected a random row, to only show the title part of it:

```
import random

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    title = f.readlines()

for i in range(0, 100):
    choice = random.choice(title)
    print(choice.split('|')[0].strip())
```

Alternatively you can process the file immediately after you've read it:

```
import random

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    title = [line.split('|')[0].strip() for line in f.readlines()]

for i in range(0, 100):
    print(random.choice(title))
```

Here's a demonstration how the `.split('|')[0].strip()` works:

```
>>> choice = "title1      | author1"
>>> choice.split('|')
['title1      ', ' author1']
>>> choice.split('|')[0]
'title1      '
>>> choice.split('|')[0].strip()
'title1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `title` after you read it in. If my text file is

```
title1 | author1
title2 | author2
```

`title` will be `['title1 ', ' author1\ntitle2 ', ' author2\n']`. Randomly choosing from this list will sometimes give you titles, sometimes authors, and sometimes both.

A better approach would something like the following:

```py
import random

# read in the file and split lines
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
# lines = ["title1 | author1", "title2 | author2"]

titles = [line.split("|")[0].strip() for line in lines]
# titles = ["title1", "title2"]
```

Note that we need to call `strip` to strip any extra whitespace off the ends of the title.

You can now proceed with your sampling, but I suspect that you want 100 *unique* titles and not just 100 random titles. What you are doing is called [sampling *with* replacement](https://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/basic-statistics/sampling-with-replacement.html), and getting unique titles would be [sampling *without* replacement](https://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/basic-statistics/sampling-without-replacement.html). You can accomplish this with `random.sample` as follows (see [the random docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)):

```py
print(*(random.sample(titles, 100)), sep = "\n")
```

or equivalently with more familiar syntax

```py
for samp_title in random.sample(titles, 100):
    print(samp_title)
```

Comment: Sure thing. Make sure to mark one of the answers as the definitive answer if you're satisfied. I think all three of us basically said the same thing, so your choice ;)